# How to create different colour shades to column bar in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am New to D3 js
I am trying to create different shades to column e.g:

- if the dataset value 40 then range 0 to 40 then colour red
- if the dataset value 89 then range 0 to 89 then colour red(range 0 to 40) + blue(range 41 to 89) and so on.

I have try [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6bvptsej/).

```
var dataset = [40,89,35,66,97,176];

var height = 400,
width =600,
offset =20,
barwidth=30;

var svg = d3.selectAll('#chart')
.append('svg')
.attr('width', width)
.attr('height', height)
.style('background','#ccc')

svg.selectAll('rect')
.data(dataset)
.enter()
.append('rect')

.style('fill',function(d){
    if(d==40)
    {
        return 'red';
    }
    else
    {
        return 'blue';
    }
})
.attr('width', barwidth)
.attr('height',function(d,i){
    return d;
})
.attr('x', function(d,i){
    return i * (barwidth+offset);
})
.attr('y', function(d ,i){
    return height - d;
});
```

Comment: `if(d < 40) { return 'red'; } else { return 'blue';}`

Comment: no,I have already done this I need different colour in one column for different range

Comment: If you've already done that edit your question accordingly, because it's not what I'm seeing.

Comment: I have to create different shades colours in one column is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33759731/d3-create-bars-of-many-colored-rectangles

Comment: thanks Gerardo Furtado it works